# Desktop lagging and general problems with an ATI X1550

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

So recently i installed Ubuntu 11.10 and first thing i always do is checking additional drivers but nothing shows there , and when i go to "System Info" > "Graphic" there is "Driver:Unknown Experience:Standard" , but experience is not even close to standard. I know that AMD have bad driver support for Linux based OS but i am experiencing some bad situations like: "blank screen" (neither unity launch bar or upper taskbar or whatever is showing up, and i can't do nothing about it, neither reset or start up system monitor.) this is very annoying to me and its causing few more problems, it sometimes seems like "Ubuntu is lagging". So if you know how to fix that stuff please tell me. 
Thank you.

Comment: BAD support? they HAD bad support like 3 years ago they are doing better much better now!, most likely your card is not supported by the AMD driver anymore so use the open source ones. instead

Comment: Have you tried 'sudo apt-get install fglrx' in the terminal then rebooting?

Comment: In the Additional Drivers window - what drivers (if any) are offered to you?

Comment: Additional Drivers don't show anything... :/

Comment: in fact i did't, i will try that now and then give you feedback.

Comment: This command just set my login to Unity 2D and it runs much slower now , nothing besides that changed. Do you maybe know how to revert this action?

Comment: That was command for installing X.Org isn't it?

Comment: It installs the proprietary AMD driver.

Comment: Uninstalling fglrx if need be is quite easy: http://goo.gl/tDWgK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dash.. when you type AMD do you see the the AMD Catalyst Control Center (Administrative)? If 'yes' login and click on 'Display Options' and 'Tear Free'. You want to disable 'Tear Free'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try open source Radeon driver check here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

As well as this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865348

Hope it helps.